# adding reference for wsdl service in windows service and using its function in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-services, wsdl

I have a windows service using C#(windows application) which performs a set of various functions.
But recently it was required to use a wsdl service (a url was provided) whose functions I have to use in my code.
Although I have never done it before but if I am not wrong we add the service reference creates its instance and then call its function.
I have done all these successfully.
But when i execute the service I get end point not found exception something like as below..

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: Could not connect to http://localhost:8082/quali-jaxrpc/quali. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8082.  ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8082
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

The problem is that the service is already running on the server itself but yet it is giving this exception..
Am I doing something wrong?

Please note that my service is not WCF its windows service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I added the service reference of the WSDL in appconfig following was created-

```
 <endpoint address="http://localhost:8082/qualicision-jaxrpc/qualicision"
```

So i just replaced the localhost with the IP of the server.

Although the service is deployed on the server and windows service also running on same but still adding actual IP of the server in place of localhost worked.